# How can I enable plugins for elasticsearch in Moqui?

Tags: moqui

I am not able to configure plugins for elasticsearch like logstash in Moqui. What should be the path in configuration file (i.e. elasticsearch.yml) for the plugins that I want to use and if I configure that path will the plugin work as expected?

Comment: This seems like more of an Elasticsearch question than a Moqui one, i.e. you would use the Elasticsearch configuration like you mentioned to add ES plugins. Is there a plugin you tried to configure that didn't work? If so, that may be more of a discussion for the LinkedIn forum than a question with a clear answer that would be good on Stack Overflow.